# Android: как называется элемент UI

Tags: android, ui, gui

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите пожалуйста, что за элемент используется в приложение ВК?

[image]

Это кастомизированная кнопка?

Comment: можно и с TextView тоже самое проделать

Comment: можно textview, можно кнопку - андроид тем и хорошо что почти все что угодно можно без серьезных затрат какстомезировать

Comment: @Роман Захаров , @gadfil - Начал кастомизировать кнопку, но наткнулся на трудность, как только я меня бэкграунд, при нажатии на кнопку не проиходит её подсвечивание, т.е. нажатие срабатывает, но это никаки не подсвечивается на экране

Answer (score 0, accepted):

это потому что не задешь как она должна выглядеть когда нажата, почитай вот это http://megadarja.blogspot.ru/2011/03/android-xml-drawables.html